# Visual Studio copys .config file to bin on build, but MSBuild does not

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, web-config

I have a WebAPI project in Visual Studio 2013.  If I build the project in Visual Studio, in the bin/ directory I see a file called MyProject.dll.config, which represents the web.config file at build time.

However, if I execute MSBuild from the command line, the .config file is missing, but all other files are present.

```
> msbuild.exe /t:build /v:q /p:Configuration=Debug /nologo \
  D:\Workspace\MyProject\src\MyProject.sln
```

What gives?  Why isn't the .config copied?

Comment: Could it be related to this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/21745579/130352 ... you seem to have the opposite issue to that question, but it may be the same root cause.

Answer (score 5):

For deploying a web project or a web api project, the fact that there's no $(TargetName)$(TargetExt).config isn't a big deal. At run-time, IIS will use Web.config to figure out everything it needs for your assembly.

BUT!

If you're using a Web App or Web Api project as the basis for testing* then you can hit some snags. In particular, when it comes to assembly binding redirects (as is the case with something within the bowels of MVC which still relies on Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.0 when the current version at time of writing is 7.0.0). A colleague had a similar issue with another assembly his test project was depending on.

Now when you run your tests through Visual Studio (eg, via Resharper), they all work just fine. However, when your tests get to the CI server and they are run by nunit-console, you'll see assembly load errors. Not pretty. This is because of the described behaviour where VS is sneakily copying the .config file to the correct output and msbuild isn't. However, you can work around this with a post-build build event:

copy $(ProjectDir)Web.Config $(TargetDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt).config

This has resolved my issues with redirects. I hope it helps someone else.

- You may ask "Why use a Web App or Web API project as your test project?". A Web* project is a lot more comfortable to deal with as a base for a test project which deals with .net assemblies and JavaScript tests as JavaScript is properly recognised (syntax highlighting) and there's a Scripts folder which has the quick "Add -> Javascript File" menu item for itself and descendant folders, so I prefer to use this instead of a plain Class Library project.

Comment: This should be the accepted anwer. The apparent bug is a feature and as long as the dll.config doesn't create problems, you should ignore it. Just don't deploy it to your production server :)

Comment: I was auto testing and my tests retrieved a keys from the <My Test Project>.dll.config and at that point the tests often failed. The MS bug described above was the problem. I changed my tests to use the app.config and hey presto, problem solved. Thanks daf! This is still an issue in VS2017.

Answer (score 1):

When I create a WebAPI project the web.config `Copy to Output Directory` is set to `Do Not Copy` by default. Did you select the Web.config in Solution Explorer and set this to a copy action?

I'm at a loss to explain why it seems to copy for you with the IDE build but NOT the msbuild cmd you show, this is not the behavior I see with a fresh WebAPI project in 2013.

Comment: Huh, that's interesting.  So I just created a brand new WebAPI project from scratch.  VS 2013 (v 12.0.21005.1 REL).  I observe the same behavior as in my other project - if I build from VS, I get the myproject.dll.config.  If I wipe the directory and use the above msbuild command, I get everything but the config file.  Literally all but the config file - if I then go into VS and rebuild, I get 1 additional file in the bin/ directory, which is the .config

Comment: As a follow up, if set Web.config to `Copy to Output Directory`, it will in fact copy the actual web.config as well as the default transforms... but it does not name it myproject.dll.config.  Actually, to clarify, VS still generated the .dll.config, *and* copies the web.*.config files, while msbuild still skips the .dll.config but copies the web.*.config files.

Comment: Interesting, I have same exact version :). Use msbuild with logging by adding a /flp:logfile="{yourPathTologFile.log}";verbosity=diagnostic. You should see a 'Copy' Task and various other activities with the dll.config.

Comment: So, it would seem that the .config file in the bin isn't being used for anything anyway.  It occurred to me that if I edit the web.config directly, VS sees that as a change and reloads it.  Much the same way IIS does.  Similarly, when you deploy the application, it uses a file called web.config, not appname.dll.config.  I'm not sure why VS creates a appname.dll.config for the webapi project from visual studio, because it appears it is not being used anyway.

Comment: Hi Matt, I have the same problem. It looks like the appname.dll.config file is not used but have you found out how to prevent Visual Studio from producing it?

Comment: @Anthony No, never did figure out why it creates that dll.  Once I got my actual use case working, I moved on (transforming the correct .config, instead of the .dll config)

Comment: I also have the same problem. VS 2012 does not make a copy but VS 2013 does... I need to copy own file with such name (using copy to output feature), because my app uses appname.dll.config directly. But VS overwrites my config by renamed web.config. VS 2013 is most buggy release of all since VS6.